# Does a Linux brand cause a Dell Latitude D620 notebook to hang during reboot process?

Tags: shutdown, reboot, trisquel

Recently, I installed Linux Trisquel 6 on a Dell Latitude D620 notebook (dual core cpu, 2GB DDR and 60GB hard drive), where previously Windows XP was installed.
But Trisquel doesn't seem to support certain driver software though, like Dell.
WiFi drivers are missing on Trisquel 6 and for those I installed other drivers and that worked out well. Then on that same disk, after Trisquel 7 formatted that disk, the upgrade was performed. Yet during final reboot the system hung with an error stating something about low on left space. But that was not possible since Trisquel 6 has already been installed on this same Seagate 60GB disk without any errors. After formatting whole disk again and reinstalling Trisquel 7 it ended with the same error, low on left space.
An installation of Trisquel 7 with the same installation disk on another notebook went well, even with lower hardware specs like slower cpu (single cpu) and 1GB memory

So, I removed Trisquel 7 and installed Linux Mint instead (17.2 Rafaela, Cinamon 32-bit 4.9.3.2).
That went well, yet after 2 or 3 reboots, the Dell Latitude D620 hung during reboot. 
After forced shutdown, the system remain unable to boot.
When pressing the start button, only leds flashing like on normal boot and I can hear the hdd spin up and the cpu for a few seconds, then it goes down again.

In fact, it doesn´t even get to the POST (bios).

Only after disconnecting the cmos battery from the MoBo and reconnecting it again, the notebook performs a normal boot.
However during a reboot after updates, the system hung again and remain unable to boot.
So I had to disconnect the cmos battery again, just to make the notebook performing a normal boot again.
I haven't yet re-installed XP again, just to find out if hanging during reboot is also persistant with Windows.
But I wondered if Linux does cause these problems?

Comment: It wouldn't be a terribly useful OS if it set out to hang a PC each time it was used. Please could you [edit your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/250187/edit) to confirm the version of Mint. What "certain driver software" do you think you're missing? Have you checked « your favourite search engine »™ to confirm hardware compatibility?

Comment: It's the latest version of Mint and no missing drivers on Mint, however WiFi drivers are missing on Trisquel.

Comment: It's the latest version of Mint and no missing drivers on Mint, however WiFi drivers are missing on Trisquel 6 and for those I installed other drivers and that worked. After upgrade to Trisquel 7, during reboot the system hung. It did not hang with Mint, latest version. The system hung again during reboot after Mint updates. Ever since the system also hangs during shutdown process.

Comment: And yes, before installing I use to check for compatibility.

Comment: For clarity please state the version of Mint you're using. IN THE QUESTION with the other information you've provied.

Comment: This is the information found: 17.2 Rafaela, Cinamon 32-bit 4.9.3.2

Answer (score 0):

After updating all software packages, still the system did not shutdown appropriatly.
Next, I cleaned up all unused installed packages.
I finally updated the kernel and shutdown the notebook.
The system now prepares to shutdown and finally shutdown appropriately.
Later that day I was able to restart the notebook, no issues.
Next day I still was able to boot into Linux Mint.
Conclusion here:
After completing installation, execute updates and finally update or upgrade the kernel.
It works for me.